# Looking for options to visually document some seriously messy matlab code

Tags: code-documentation

I would like to document some sprawling, 2-decade old matlab code visually. Meaning, like a flow diagram that is layered. I know this must exist; I'm terrified that UML is the answer. I'm hoping to avoid the learning curve since I don't plan to ever actually generate code with my diagrams.

For example, say I have a top level function. It has several functions, and each one of those also calls a series of functions. I would like to see visually how all these pieces are linked together, with the ability to zoom in/out. Obviously, I first want to understand all the gnarly details and then rewrite the code cleanly in OO Matlab or Python.

Does this exist? Or should I figure out what type of UML template would work best?

I've searched through gliffy documentation, b/c that is the UML environment we have on Confluence. However, I believe this may be overkill.